# Simple jQuery script works in Chrome, broken in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple bit of jQuery that populates a field with a random string after 3 seconds.

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5sLrtg5t/

If you load this demo in IE 11, it doesn't populate the field. Why is this?

```
function makeid()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for( var i=0; i < 8; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    return text;
}

var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var keys = urlParams.keys();
for (key of keys) {}
setTimeout(function() {
  if(document.location.search.length) {
  } else {
    $('#address').val(makeid());
  }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: error in dev tools console should give you clues...what is it?

Comment: My console says: `'URLSearchParams' is undefined`

Comment: right..because that api is not supported in IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a [for ... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) which isn't supported by IE, try using a `for ... in` instead (using [Object.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) if you want a similar behavior):

```
function makeid()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for( var i=0; i < 8; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    return text;
}

var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var keys = urlParams.keys();
for (key in keys) {}
setTimeout(function() {
  if(document.location.search.length) {
  } else {
    $('#address').val(makeid());
  }
}, 3000);
```

I'll be honest the point of that second for loop confuses me, you might be able to get rid of it entirely.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments by @charlietfl [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) as a whole is also not supported.

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) has a nice function that I believe should do something similar to what you're trying to do:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Alternatively there are also quite a few libraries out there to be able to use the URL API on non-supported browswers, [WebReflection/url-search-params](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params) is just one of the few that showed up from a  quick google search.

Comment: Don't think URL API is supported either

Comment: @PatrickBarr That doesn't seem to resolve the issue. I'm still getting this in my Console `'URLSearchParams' is undefined`.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk why don't you define URLSearchParams then?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk as charlietfl pointed out, that's also not supported by IE *cough* classic *cough* you'll need to work around it, I edited my answer to include another SO post on that matter as well as a github repo that seems to define it so it is usable in browsers that don't support it

Comment: Many thanks for your help, Patrick. I will investigate this shortly.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk glad I could be of help!